# How to add filename or title in react syntax hightligting

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, strapi, react-markdown, react-syntax-highlighter

Hi I've successfully add react syntax hightlight to my project that using gatsbyjs and strapi, from strapi the content was formatted in markdown so i've add `react-markdown` and `react-syntax-hightlight` to handle rendering and syntax hightlighting in my application

here's from what i've implemented so far

###### Article.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown"
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter"
import { vscDarkPlus } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism"
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw"
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm"
import remarkSlug from "remark-slug"
import "../../../styles/language.css"

const ArticleContent = ({ content }) => {
  return (
    <ReactMarkdown
      remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm, remarkSlug]}
      rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
      children={content}
      linkTarget="_blank"
      transformImageUri={uri =>
        uri.startsWith("http") ? uri : `${process.env.GATSBY_ROOT_URL}${uri}`
      }
      components={{
        code({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }) {
          const match =
            className !== undefined
              ? className.replace("language-", "")
              : "code"
          return !inline && match ? (
            <div className="relative">
              {(match !== "shell-session" || match === null) && (
                <p
                  className={`code-hightlight language-${match} font-jost text-sm font-light tracking-wide rounded-b absolute right-2 -top-5 px-2 py-1 bg-tertiary`}
                >
                  {match}
                </p>
              )}
              <SyntaxHighlighter
                children={String(children).replace(/\n$/, "")}
                style={vscDarkPlus}
                language={match}
                PreTag="div"
                {...props}
              />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <code className={`rounded-md ${className}`} {...props}>
              {children}
            </code>
          )
        },
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default ArticleContent
```

here i've implemented latest react markdown and how to add syntax highlight above.
here's what is look like

[image]

From this i want to add some title or filename for example App.js before displaying the syntax highlight. Since this is using markdown so how am i suppose to do to achieve this?

here's the currently formatted markdown to display that syntax hightlight above

````
```jsx
 const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { text: "Buy Food", isCompleted: false },
    { text: "Learn React", isCompleted: true },
    { text: "Build todo app", isCompleted: true }
  ]);

  //...
}
```
````